# Finding the cartesian product of two power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

CONTEXT: Finding the cartesian product of two power sets.

If $A=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$ and $B=\{\emptyset, \{3\}\}$, then how do you find the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$?

I think it might be $A×B=\{\emptyset, \{(1,3)\}, \{2,3\}, \{(2,2)\}, \{(1,3), (2,2)\}\}$ but am not sure if this is right.

Comment: Hint: if the question is confusing you in its present form, call the four elements of the first set $a,b,c,d$, call the elements of the second set $e,f$, find the Cartesian product and substitute back.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Your pairs have to consists of elements of the set A and B, which in this case are sets. For example, $ (\{2\},\{3\}) \in A \times B$.

Comment: UPDATE: Okay, I've done this and ended up with a set of 8 elements. What happens when you have an elements containing the empty set such as $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$, $(a, \emptyset)$? I've also got the element $(\{1,2\}, \{3\})$, can you have an ordered pair with a set of two numbers?

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct. $A \times B$ contains pairs of sets. An element of $A \times B$ is of the form $(M,N)$, where $M \in A$ and $N \in B.$

For example we have $(\{2\},\{3\}) \in A \times B$, and not $\{2,3\} \in A \times B$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If $A,B$ are any sets, then
$$
A \times B = \{(a,b) | a \in A, b \in B\}.
$$

For example, if $A = \{a,b,c\},B=\{x,y\}$, then
$$
A \times B = \{(a,x),(a,y),(b,x),(b,y),(c,x),(c,y)\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Ordered pair** a pair of elements( possible to be sets themselves), where the order tells you about which set it came from.

**Cartesian product** a Set of all n-tuples ( a general form of ordered pair, that can deal with any number of sets), ordered by the way the sets in the product are ordered.

$A×B=
\{(\emptyset,\emptyset),(\emptyset,\{3\}),(\{1\},\emptyset),(\{1\},\{3\}),(\{2\},\emptyset),(\{2\},\{3\}),(\{1,2\},\emptyset),(\{1,2\},\{3\})\}$

The product $B×A$ would reverse the order in each of these pairs.